# How to get all offers of item in aws amazon api (ItemLookup)

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, web-services

I am calling the ItemLookUp amazon API to get all the offers of the item but in the response it show the total offer 4 but in the "offers" it return only one offer details. How I can get the all 4 offer details? In response group I have used "Offers" and "OfferFull" but both did not returned expected result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list of ALL offers from Amazon Product Advertising API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204896/get-list-of-all-offers-from-amazon-product-advertising-api) Short answer: it's not possible with the API I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes i also searched, it is not possible from api.

Comment: You can however set `Condition=All` to get one offer per condition type (one for 'New', one for 'Used', one for 'Refurbished' etc.) By default, only the offer for `Condition=New` is returned.